# Make Spring Boot 3 Actuator aware of X-Forwarded-Prefix header?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

This question is similar to [Make Spring Boot 2.7.x Actuator aware of X-Forwarded-Prefix header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462994/make-spring-boot-actuator-aware-of-x-forwarded-prefix-header), but for Spring Boot 3.

We're using Spring Boot 3 with `spring-boot-starter-actuator` that we're exposing on port 8081 under the `/management` context path. The proxy sets several `X-Forwarded-*` headers, including the `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header that is set to `/service`. But when navigating to `https://www.company.com/management` this is what is returned:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management",
            "templated": false
        },
        "beans": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/beans",
            "templated": false
        },
        "caches-cache": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/caches/{cache}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "caches": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/caches",
            "templated": false
        },
        "health": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/health",
            "templated": false
        },
        "health-path": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/health/{*path}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "info": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/info",
            "templated": false
        },
        "conditions": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/conditions",
            "templated": false
        },
        "configprops": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/configprops",
            "templated": false
        },
        "configprops-prefix": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/configprops/{prefix}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "env": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/env",
            "templated": false
        },
        "env-toMatch": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/env/{toMatch}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "integrationgraph": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/integrationgraph",
            "templated": false
        },
        "loggers": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/loggers",
            "templated": false
        },
        "loggers-name": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/loggers/{name}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "heapdump": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/heapdump",
            "templated": false
        },
        "threaddump": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/threaddump",
            "templated": false
        },
        "metrics-requiredMetricName": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/metrics/{requiredMetricName}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "metrics": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/metrics",
            "templated": false
        },
        "scheduledtasks": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/scheduledtasks",
            "templated": false
        },
        "sessions-sessionId": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/sessions/{sessionId}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "sessions": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/sessions",
            "templated": false
        },
        "mappings": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/mappings",
            "templated": false
        },
        "refresh": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/refresh",
            "templated": false
        },
        "features": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/features",
            "templated": false
        },
        "traces": {
            "href": "https://www.company.com/management/traces",
            "templated": false
        }
    }
}
```

I want the href's in the response to start with `https://www.company.com/service` due to the supplied `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header. It *won't* work by simply adding a `ForwardedHeaderFilter`:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> forwardedHeaderFilterFilterRegistrationBean() {
    ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter = new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(forwardedHeaderFilter);
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

I added an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32475) at Spring Boot GitHub, and they acknowledged that the behavior is a bit confusing (since it works in webflux). However, in Spring Boot 2.7, this workaround could be applied to make it work:

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnManagementPort(ManagementPortType.DIFFERENT)
public class ManagementContextFactoryBeanPostProcessor
        implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof ManagementContextFactory managementContextFactory) {
            return (ManagementContextFactory) (parent, configurationClasses) -> {
                var context = managementContextFactory.createManagementContext(parent, configurationClasses);
                if (context instanceof GenericWebApplicationContext genericWebApplicationContext) {
                    genericWebApplicationContext.registerBean(ForwardedHeaderFilterRegistrationBean.class);
                }
                return context;
            };
        }
        return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean, beanName);
    }

    public static class ForwardedHeaderFilterRegistrationBean
            extends FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> {

        public ForwardedHeaderFilterRegistrationBean() {
            setFilter(new ForwardedHeaderFilter());
            setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        }

    }

}
```

But this no longer works in Spring Boot 3. The `ManagementContextFactory` is no longer an interface but rather a final class, and the signature of the `createManagementContext` method has changed.

So my question is, how can I make actuator take the `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header into account when generating the links to the endpoints behind a proxy in Spring Boot 3?

Comment: add `server.forward-headers-strategy: NATIVE` in your application config file

Comment: Doesn't work. I've also tried `management.server.forward-headers-strategy: NATIVE`

Comment: If you start with a fresh initializr project and add web and actuator starters, the `FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter>` you have above _does_ appear to change the prefix for me locally. Is it possible you have another filter in your chain that is undoing what the `ForwardedHeaderFilter` is doing? By unwrapping the decorated request object?

Comment: What if you use Spring's forwarding strategy with `server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to workaround this problem with the following code (worked for me with Spring Boot 3.1.0):

```
@Bean
@Primary
public static ManagementContextFactory myServletWebChildContextFactory() {
    return new ManagementContextFactory(WebApplicationType.SERVLET, ServletWebServerFactory.class,
            ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, MyForwardedHeaderFilterAutoConfiguration.class);
}

static class MyForwardedHeaderFilterAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> myForwardedHeaderFilter() {
        ForwardedHeaderFilter filter = new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
        FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR);
        registration.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

The @Primary annotation should ensure that the ManagementContextFactory above is used by Spring. Additionally we define own auto-configuration class defining FilterRegistrationBean for the ForwardedHeaderFilter (as it is missing in the management context and the one from parent context is not registered). The auto-configuration class is then passed as the last parameter to the ManagementContextFactory constructor in the bean factory method.